# How to create static pages using JSON Stream of local data source in Gridsome

Tags: gridsome

I have a large JSON file that I would like to use as a local data source for Gridsome to generate static pages.

I would like to stream the data in rather than load it all into memory.

Something like this in `gridsome.server.js`:

```javascript
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.loadSource(async (actions) => {
    const collection = actions.addCollection({
      typeName: 'Posts',
    })
    const StreamArray = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray')
    const fs = require('fs')

    const jsonStream = StreamArray.withParser()

    //internal Node readable stream option, pipe to stream-json to convert it for us
    fs.createReadStream('./src/data/posts.json').pipe(jsonStream.input)

    //You'll get json objects here
    //Key is the array-index here
    jsonStream.on('data', ({ key, value }) => {
      collection.addNode(value)
    })

    jsonStream.on('end', ({ key, value }) => {
      console.log('All Done')
    })
  })
}
```

Are there flaws in this approach? I am wondering if this might not work because of the async nature of it. Anyone tried anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any flaws in this approach?

NO - this should work.